# How to determine the accurate image dimension in px of an ImageView in a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, size, android-drawable

If I had an `ImageView` with fixed width and height (the width and height of the `ImageView` **layout**) it would be really easy to determine the accurate dimension of the image in px in the `mdpi` folfer.

For example, if the width and height were 500x500dp, in the `mdpi` folder, the image.png should be 500x500px and the image dimension of the rest densities it would be as easy as converting those 500x500dp to the rest of the densities.

Okay, but this isn't my case. As the title says, now suppose I am using an `ImageView` in a `ConstraintLayout`, so this `ImageView` has some start,end,top and bottom constraints and the width and height are `match_parent` (`0dp` in `ConstraintLayout`). Okay, so now that the width and height are not fixed as before, how could I know the dimension in px of the `mdpi` folder?

What I have thought to solve this:

What I have thought is to `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` in pixels of the `ImageView` **layout** in an arbitrary `mdpi` device so that if the width and height of the `ImageView` **layout** is for example 300x200px, that would be also the image dimension in px in the `mdpi` folder. Okay but this is not quite correct as there are other devices with `mdpi` density that have smaller and bigger screens so the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` of the `ImageView` **layout** would be different in those devices although they are also `mdpi`.

**So how can I know what dimension in px of the image should be in the mdpi folder?** I have been struggling with this many months and I have not found any information neither in the official documentation nor in other posts...

Comment: Does this help: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-ImageView

Comment: @BillMair well, the only related thing I have found is this: "This means that if you generate a 100x100 for mdpi (1x baseline), then you should generate the same resource in 150x150 for hdpi (1.5x)" .Okay that is obvious, but, it doesn't explain why in the mdpi folder it is stored a 100x100px, that is what I want to know, how to determine that dimension of the .png image in the mdpi folder, the rest of converting it to the other densities is much simpler and mechanic

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of ConstraintLayout is to solve complex set of constraints the produce an appropriate dimensions.

If by "know" you mean at run time you can ask the view after layout.

```
view.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener(){
public void onLayoutChange(View v,
   int left,    int    top, int    right, int   bottom,
   int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

})
```

If by "know" you mean ahead of time. You can look at the implications of the Constraints and solve the math yourself. This can be non trivial.
If it depends on Fields with wrap_content, Aspect ratio of phone etc.

For simple use cases it is easy say

```xml
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

We know this will be the size of the ConstraintLayout which may ore may not be the size of the screen. We cannot know ahead of time because the screen size is unknown ahead of time. So you need to get this at run time.

Comment: But this answer is explaining how to get the dimension of the ImageView layout (the View in your example) . What I want is to know the accurate dimension of the image.png in px that should be stored in the mdpi folder, I am talking about the dimension of the .png file, I am not talking about the dimension of the layout of the image, also I don't want to get any value, I want to know what dimension of the .png file should be set in the mdpi folder. Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: ImageView scales the image based on what mode it is set. 
See https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide
So in general pic a resolution close what would give 1 to 1 on a 6 inch phone. 
There is no exact answer that works for all needs.

Comment: I don't see it really clear, why on a 6 inch phone and not on a 8 inch phone? Imagine that the width and height of the ImageView Layout is 500x500px in a 6 inch device (obtaining that width and height using getWidth() and getHeight() of the ImageView), then, according to your answer, the dimension of the .png file in the mdpi folder should be 500x500px?

Comment: If you are trying to have an image that fits 1 to 1 with the screen then that is going to require many images. One for each known screen width. 
ImageView automatically scales images so the most reasonable thing to do is scale the image to 2 or 3 typical sizes and let imageView do the rest. 
Alternative is to use vector drawables which are drawn and the desired scale.

Comment: what do you mean by "fits 1 to 1"? Also, when you say: "scale the image to 2 or 3 typical sizes" do you refer to make different images for different densities or you are not talking about densities?  Could you put me an example? For example imagine that the width and height of the ImageView is 0dp and all the constraints is "parent" and the parent is the whole screen. In short words, could you put me an example of the accurate dimensions of the image.png in the mdpi folder for an ImageView that occupies the whole screen?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. 
Any Image put in such and ImageView with android:scaleType="centerCrop" will fill the screen. Depending on the aspect ratio of the image and screen some part would be cropped. Maybe this might help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/imageview-scaletype-in-android-with-example/